# .Net core - Can not upload file after deploy to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm create an api can upload excel file with multipart/form-data. When I run on visual studo, it work normally. But, after deploy to IIS, it can not upload and throw error as below:

> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource.

I try setting with web.config but it still not work, event api POST, GET, DELETE with json context still working normally.

Comment: Could you show us how you have your `public void Configure(...)` method setup?

Answer (score 1):

[Have a look at the docs on CORS setup in .net core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors)

In Startup you use `services.AddCors()` to specify a policy e.g.

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com",
                                        "http://www.contoso.com");
                });
            });

            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

Comment: I try and it not still not working.
note: it working normally with normal api, only api upload not work

Comment: In the docs, it mentions you can use `.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();` to the bulider, did you try this?

Comment: @user3409461 are you sure that your content-type is correct for your upload and that the file is not too large? Cors errors can sometimes mask other error messages